# calculate float in 0-1 range for every item in array using ease

Tags: javascript, algorithm, animation, math

I am currently working on animations related project and i am struggling with adding ease effect to the numbers.

Lets say we have an array of `n` objects, each object among other parameters is holding opacity value. For the time being i just made it so opacity is going in `linear` way from `1` to `0` (first element has opacity `1` while last element has `0`).

This is the code:

```js
document.body.innerHTML += '<style>.item,body{margin:5px}body{background:#000}.item{width:75px;height:75px;float:left;position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;border:1px solid red}.bg,.text{position:absolute;top:0;left:0}.text{width:100%;height:100%;font-size:30px;text-align:center;line-height:75px;color:#fff}.bg{background:red;width:calc(100% - 2px);height:calc(100% - 2px);margin:1px}</style><div class="wrap"></div>';

let array = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
 array.push(i);
}

for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 let linearOpacity = 1 - i / (array.length - 1);
 console.log(linearOpacity);
 document.querySelector('.wrap').innerHTML += (
   '<div class="item">' +
    '<div class="bg" style="opacity:' + linearOpacity + ';"></div>' +
    '<div class="text">' + i + '</div>' +
   '</div>'
  );
}
```

Now how to implement ease formula that will cause opacity to decrease slowly at the beginning so it will stay high for longer and then decrease more rapidly closer to the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of x going from 1 to 0 use this function:

```
a = -1.2 * t / (-t - 0.2)
```

where t goes from 1 to 0 gradually and then rapidly.

To see the affect you can run the code:

```
for t in range(10, -1, -1):
    t = t / 10
    a = -1.2 * t / (-t - 0.2)
    print(t, '----> \t\t', a)
```

which gives the following output:

```
1.0 ---->        1.0
0.9 ---->        0.9818181818181818
0.8 ---->        0.96
0.7 ---->        0.9333333333333333
0.6 ---->        0.8999999999999999
0.5 ---->        0.8571428571428572
0.4 ---->        0.7999999999999998
0.3 ---->        0.72
0.2 ---->        0.6
0.1 ---->        0.3999999999999999
0.0 ---->        0.0
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, it does the job perfectly, thank you sir, just out of curiosity, if i would like later on reverse effect - that its decreasing rapidly at the beginning and then slowly closer to the end, how `a` would have to look like? ;)

Comment: Easy, it will a reflection function in the y= x line, which is `a = -0.2 * t / (t - 1.2)`

Comment: If its right you can mark it as the correct answer.